# Command-line argument program from book doesn't work...(C)

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments, codeblocks

Near the end of Chapter 13, a program demonstrating command-line arguments which is supposed to print

```
Jupiter is planet 5
venus is not a planet
Earth is planet 3
fred is not a planet
```

upon input of

```
planet Jupiter venus Earth fred
```

I checked the chapters code with mine and everything checks out, I am using Code:Blocks and compiling as C99.

When I run the program the program ends immediately, asking to press any key to exit.

```
    // Checks planet names

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define NUM_PLANETS 9

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char *planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth",
                           "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn",
                           "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
        int i, j;

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS; j++)
                if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) {
                    printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
                    break;
                }
            if (j == NUM_PLANETS)
                printf("%s is not a planet\n", argv[i]);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply command line arguments.

With CodeBlocks you can set it like this :

```
Project > Set programs' arguments...
```

This opens a window where you can insert your parameters. Give the input here :

```
Jupiter venus Earth fred
```